RD Web Application in not launching
RD Web Application in not launching after i changed the port number in below path.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
I can able to connect the direct rdp in MSTSC (IP Address:portnumber)
Note: We are not using RD Web Gateway server
I created rules for custom port in firewall both inbound and outbound rules.
I can able to telnet the Server IP with custom port number
